# Get last entry from every table in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I am testing a failover of MySQL server. One of the checks would be an integrity check, to see if it contains the same data. For this I'd like to get last entries from EACH table in a database.

I know how to retrieve data from a single table, but how would I run this for ~100 tables?

Happy to consider better options for integrity checks.

Comment: You could run the same operation for each table directly.  Or perhaps query system tables to get a list of table names and then run it for each result from there.  Though it's worth noting that "the last entry" is only meaningful with an explicit and meaningful `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Agree regarding the ORDER BY, and running the same operation individually for each table is definitely an option but that's something I'd like to avoid for obvious reasons. Didn't think of pulling a list of tables - will give it a go, cheers!

Comment: If this is a fail over senario, where are you going to get the last rows from to compare against. The now failed database wont be accessible :) It crashed, or the server it is on crashed